# TSQL - Percentage calculation not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created subqueries which return a count e.g. below;

I am trying to code them as **LH / (GN + MarketRent + Commercial) * 100** but where there is a value to calculate the query returns a null.

subquery which joins the main query, using left  outer.

```
SELECT        BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] AS [BLOCK-SUBB-REF], count(BLOCKS.[PLACE-REF]) NoOfMR
FROM            [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] AS BLOCKS INNER JOIN
                         [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] AS SUBB ON BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] = SUBB.[PLACE-REF] 
                         AND SUBB.[LOCATION-TYPE] IN ('BLOCK', 'SUBBLOCK', 'CBLOCK', 'HOSTEL', 'SCHEME') --and  SUBB.[BLOCK-REF] <> ''
                         and BLOCKS.[LOCATION-TYPE] in ('FLAT', 'BEDSIT', 'BUNG', 'DUPLEX', 'ENDTER', 'GFLAT', 'GFLATOG', 'HOSTEL', 'HOUSE', 'MAISON', 'SEMDET', 'ROOM'
                         ,'BLOCK', 'SUBBLOCK', 'CBLOCK', 'HOSTEL', 'SCHEME')
                        right JOIN  [DBAdmin].[dbo].[BusinessPlanTenureMap] bp on bp.[ESTATE-CODE] = BLOCKS.[ESTATE-CODE]
WHERE 
bp.[Business Plan Tenure] = 'MARKET RENTAL' and
(BLOCKS.[LOCATION-STS] <> 'D')
group by BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF]
```

This the the code I have produced so far taking into account the divide by zero error in the main query. The % Leaseholders column shows null values rather than the % calculation.

```
,cast(nullif(isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0),0) as int)/ cast(nullif(isnull(gen.NoOfGN,0),0) + nullif(isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0),0) + nullif(isnull(cm.NoOfCM,0),0) as int) * 100 '% leaseholder'
```

[image]

```
GN  LH/SO   MARKET RENTAL   COMMERCIAL  % Leaseholders
0   0   0   0   0.00
4   2   0   0   14.29
2   2   0   0   16.67
0   0   0   0   0.00
3   1   0   0   12.50
1   3   0   0   75.00
```

The table is the expected output

Any tips advice appreciated.
Thanks

Thanks Jeremy,
This part of the query works, it totals.

```
cast(isnull((nullif((isnull(gen.NoOfGN,0) 
+ isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0) 
+isnull(mr.NoOfMR,0)
+isnull(rl.NoOfRL,0) 
+isnull(cm.NoOfCM,0) 
+isnull(hs.NoOfHS,0)
+isnull(op.NoOfOP,0)
+isnull(sh.NoOfSH,0) 
+isnull(ec.NoOfEC,0) ),0)),0)as int) Total
```

but when I add this

```
isnull(nullif(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0),0) /
```

to the front part it returns an error
Divide by zero error encountered.

I think I catered for the null values...

Comment: Take the time to post **consumable** sample data and expected results, preferably as DDL and DML statements. We don't have access to your instance, nor do we have a copy of your data, so we don't know why what you have isn't working.

Comment: ill take a stab at psychic debugging: you are using a right join. whenever you use an "outer" type join, whether right or left, if a record does not match, you have the possibility for a NULL value. I'd look outside of the calculation, and ensure that you are joining the tables correctly before blaming your calculation.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, 
This part of the query works, it totals.

cast(isnull((nullif((isnull(gen.NoOfGN,0) 
+ isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0) 
+isnull(mr.NoOfMR,0)
+isnull(rl.NoOfRL,0) 
+isnull(cm.NoOfCM,0) 
+isnull(hs.NoOfHS,0)
+isnull(op.NoOfOP,0)
+isnull(sh.NoOfSH,0) 
+isnull(ec.NoOfEC,0) ),0)),0)as int) Total

but when I add this 
isnull(nullif(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0),0) / 
to the front part it returns an error 
Divide by zero error encountered.

I think I catered for the null values...

Comment: you are using nullif which will turn a 0 value into NULL. maybe you want to try "method 2" as outlined in this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/methods-to-avoid-sql-divide-by-zero-error/

Comment: I tried method 2 but to no success, the isnull works on it's own, it's only when I try to divide the results don;t add up at all.

(case when lhso.[NoOfLH-SO] = null then 0 else cast (isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0) as int) end) /

cast(isnull(gen.NoOfGN,0) 
+ isnull(lhso.[NoOfLH-SO],0) 
+isnull(mr.NoOfMR,0)
+isnull(rl.NoOfRL,0) 
+isnull(cm.NoOfCM,0) 
+isnull(hs.NoOfHS,0)
+isnull(op.NoOfOP,0)
+isnull(sh.NoOfSH,0) 
+isnull(ec.NoOfEC,0) as int) Total

Comment: with your statement, you are calculating a percentage row by row. I suspect you want to calculate the percentage relative to all of the other rows in your recordset. see this article on how to accomplish that. (there are many techniques, this is just one) https://jimsalasek.com/2020/03/05/calculate-percentage-of-total/

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, Tried that but no joy. I am trying to calculate row by row, that should show % for that row.